# SQL Server Optimizer removes ISNULL calls

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following query runs into an error with SQL Server 2017:

```
;with locations(RowNum, Latitude, Longitude) as (
    select 1, 12.3456, 45.6789
),
locationsWithPrevious as (
    select  *,
            PreviousLatitude = lag(l.Latitude) over(order by l.RowNum),
            PreviousLongitude = lag(l.Longitude) over(order by l.RowNum)
    from    locations as l
),
locationsWithDistance as (
    select  *,
            Distance = geography::Point(l.Latitude, l.Longitude, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point(l.PreviousLatitude, l.PreviousLongitude, 4326))
    from    locationsWithPrevious as l
    where   PreviousLatitude is not null
        and PreviousLongitude is not null
)
select  *
from    locationsWithDistance as l
where   Distance > 0

Msg 6569, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
'geography::Point' failed because parameter 1 is not allowed to be null.
```

Reason:
The predicate `Distance > 0` is executed before filtering `PreviousLatitude/-Longitude` to `IS NOT NULL`.
So far so good, because T-SQL is declarative and the order of operations here can be determined by the SQL Server.
If you remove the predicate `Distance > 0`, the query works without errors.

But now I would expect that the `NULL` values of the parameters can be prevented by using `ISNULL` function as follows:

```
Distance = geography::Point(l.Latitude, l.Longitude, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point(isnull(l.PreviousLatitude, 0), isnull(l.PreviousLongitude, 0), 4326))
```

But the query still returns the same error!
The `ISNULL` function is also not listed anywhere in the filter predicate of the execution plan!

Is this behaviour of the SQL Server correct?
It looks to me like the SQL Server is incorrectly removing the `ISNULL` calls due to the `IS NOT NULL` filtering.

Notes:

1. When the `IS NOT NULL` conditions are removed, the error disappears because the `ISNULL` function is now used in the filter predicate as expected (but the query has changed semantically, of course):

   ```
    locationsWithDistance as (
        select  *,
                Distance = geography::Point(l.Latitude, l.Longitude, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point(isnull(l.PreviousLatitude, 0), isnull(l.PreviousLongitude, 0), 4326))
        from    locationsWithPrevious as l
    )
   ```
2. However, the query works correctly if you replace the `ISNULL` calls with `CASE WHEN` operations:

   ```
    Distance = geography::Point(l.Latitude, l.Longitude, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point(case when l.PreviousLatitude is not null then l.PreviousLatitude else 0 end, case when l.PreviousLongitude is not null then l.PreviousLongitude else 0 end, 4326))
   ```
3. I also realise that the query can be better formulated as follows, by instantiating the `Point` directly in the base query:

   ```
    ;with locations(RowNum, GeoPosition) as (
        select 1, geography::Point(12.3456, 45.6789, 4326)
    ),
    locationsWithPrevious as (
        select  *,
                PreviousGeoPosition = lag(l.GeoPosition) over(order by l.RowNum)
        from    locations as l
    ),
    locationsWithDistance as (
        select  *,
                Distance = l.GeoPosition.STDistance(l.PreviousGeoPosition)
        from    locationsWithPrevious as l
        where   PreviousGeoPosition is not null
    )
    select  *
    from    locationsWithDistance as l
    where   Distance > 0
   ```

Comment: Replacing `isnull` with `coalesce` also works. Looks like a bug to me, reproduced on 2016, 2017, 2019.

Comment: Have you tried created derived table `locationsWithPrevious` with `ISNULL` to select the `PreviousLatitude` and `PreviousLongitude` columns?

Comment: This certainly looks like a bug to me, it should be reported. The `where PreviousLatitude is not null and PreviousLongitude is not null` makes the server believe it's proven that those are not null, and actually remove the corresponding `isnull`s. If you replace the condition with `where PreviousLongitude is not null`, the error message will change to "parameter *2* is not allowed to be null", because then only the second `isnull` will be eliminated and the first will remain. Indeed the reason seems to be that the server fails to realize that the evaluation may happen before the `where`.

Comment: I am guessing this is the correct behavior. I don't know how `isnull` works but `case when` and `coalesce` (which is a shorter form of former) is supposed to evaluate `when` clauses in order. And SQL server is free to rewrite your query like so `WHERE Distance > 0` to `WHERE p1.stDistance(p2) > 0 AND p1 IS NOT NULL and p2 IS NOT NULL` and then by specification there is no guarantee of order in which it will be evaluated.

Comment: @SalmanA Correct, no order of evaluation is assumed by the OP. Yet the SQL Server removes the `isnull` call from inside of the expression, which is an optimization that can only be done when the order of evaluation is known to be "`where` first" - otherwise it's an optimization that changes observable behaviour, a.k.a. "bug". The OP's code, before "optimized" by the optimizer, would perform correctly regardless of the order of execution.

Comment: "... it should be reported.": where is the correct place to report a sql server bug now that uservoice has been taken out of service?

Answer (score 3):

**It does indeed appear to be a bug.** The compiler thinks the value is provably not null, and removes the `ISNULL`. However, `COALESCE` is not affected in the same way, it compiles down to `CASE` and the compiler doesn't have as much visibility on it.

The compiler puts intermediate calculations into `Compute Scalar` operators. But these can be calculated [at different points by the Expression Service](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/09/compute-scalars-expressions-and-execution-plan-performance.html), and therefore the `ISNULL` should not have been removed.

One workaround, as you have found, is to remove the `WHERE`.

Another one is to use the extra parameter on `LAG` to add a default

```sql
;with locations(RowNum, Latitude, Longitude) as (
    select 1, 12.3456, 45.6789
),
locationsWithPrevious as (
    select  *,
            PreviousLatitude = lag(l.Latitude, 1, 0) over(order by l.RowNum),
            PreviousLongitude = lag(l.Longitude, 1, 0) over(order by l.RowNum)
    from    locations as l
),
locationsWithDistance as (
    select  *,
            Distance = geography::Point(l.Latitude, l.Longitude, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point(l.PreviousLatitude, l.PreviousLongitude, 4326))
    from    locationsWithPrevious as l
)
select  *
from    locationsWithDistance as l
where   Distance > 0
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1315be73038218b581c7bf155f11b2d8)

Comment: Removing the `WHERE`condition prevents the error, but changes the semantics of the query. The same applies to the changed default values of the `LAG`. I think the best workaround (if not the best way at all to formulate this query) is to instantiate the `Point` object directly in the base query, as I described under 3.).

Comment: You could use `99999` in the `LAG` parameter, then filter `where PreviousGeoPosition <> 99999`

Comment: Then you run into the same problem again:
`99999` is an invalid value for `Longitude/Latitude` and it is not defined whether the `WHERE` is executed first or the `Point` is instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is symptomatic of chaining too much logic via common table expression.  I often find myself breaking chains via #hash tables like this simply because it's easier to debug, and a lot easier to understand.

```
drop table if exists #locationsWithPrevious;
;with locations(RowNum, Latitude, Longitude) as (
    select 1, 12.3456, 45.6789
),
locationsWithPrevious as (
    select  *,
            PreviousLatitude = lag(l.Latitude) over(order by l.RowNum),
            PreviousLongitude = lag(l.Longitude) over(order by l.RowNum)
    from    locations as l
)
    select *
    into #locationsWithPrevious
    from locationsWithPrevious
    where   PreviousLatitude is not null
        and PreviousLongitude is not null;

with locationsWithDistance as (
    select  *,
            Distance = geography::Point(l.Latitude, l.Longitude, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point(l.PreviousLatitude, l.PreviousLongitude, 4326))
    from    #locationsWithPrevious as l
)
select  *
from    locationsWithDistance as l
where   Distance > 0;
```